# The this keyword in typescript. Is it a bug?

Tags: typescript

I have a member function render(). This function calls another member of the class add(any). This is the snippet.

```
render(){
    collection.each(this.add);
}
```

If I use the keyword "this" in add, the type is window. I would expect it to be the instance of the member class.

> In a constructor, member function, or member accessor, this is of the class instance type of the containing class.

Answer (score 17):

As JcFx points out, your `this` scope is different within the `each` callback.

However, if you use a 'fat arrow' anonymous function, that will use lexical scoping rules for `this` so that you get what you're looking for:

```
render(){
    collection.each((x) => this.add(x));
}
```

Compiles to the following JavaScript:

```
X.prototype.render = function () {
    var _this = this;
    collection.each(function (x) {
        return _this.add(x);
    });
}
```

Another option is to explicitly `bind` the `add` call to the desired `this`:

```
render(){
    collection.each(this.add.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's a bug.

You are no longer in the scope of the `render()` function, but instead in the scope of `each()`.

Try this:

```
render(){
    var that = this;
    collection.each(that.add);
}
```

Comment: IMO, it IS a bug, but in the TypeScript language definition. "This" inside a class should refer to the class instance, period. The way that JavaScript changes what "this" points to depending on how the method is called is one of its worst mistakes (in a language full of them). If TypeScript wants to be a true superset of JavaScript, it can't change that for normal methods, but it can and absolutely should change it for class methods.

Comment: But you're inside a callback closure (of `each()`, not `render()`). Closure scoping is a fundamental feature of JS, and therefore TS. Anyway, it might be a *feature* that you (and the OP) don't like, but it is certainly intentional, and meets the published specification, so it isn't, by definition, a *bug*. Far too many posts on SO, IMO, trumpet apparent 'bugs' in their titles: it's a term that should be used with more care.

Comment: Agreed that it's not a bug in the implementation - just in the spec :-). Perhaps a workaround (at the spec level) would be a different keyword - `me`? - `that`? - which always pointed to the class instance, not to the object to which the method in question had been assigned.

Comment: When you say that the spec has a "bug", you're again using the term "bug" incorrectly. A spec might have a mistake, but a spec cannot have a bug, as the spec is not code.