# How do I access a class function from inside a event in the contructor?

Tags: typescript

I am adding a change event to an ID in my class constructor in typescript, and inside that change event I would like to access a class function, but 'this' seems to not be the class when inside the event. How do I access the function from there?

```
export class Document_Uploads {

        constructor() {
            $("#FormBrokerReferenceID").change(function () {
                 = $("#FormBrokerReferenceID").val();

                //inside this event it does not work           
                this.Validate()

            });

             // works here inside constructor
            this.Validate()

        }

    Validate() {
            var valid: bool = true;
             some other code
    }


}
```

Comment: The question is really about scope of `this`, and therefore a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683305/the-this-keyword-in-typescript-is-it-a-bug/13683593#13683593 (certainly the accepted answer there will help you - the key is to use a fat arrow function). VTC just to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem.

The first is to get TypeScript to handle the scope for you:

```
    constructor() {
        $("#FormBrokerReferenceID").change( () => {
             = $("#FormBrokerReferenceID").val();

            // Should now work...         
            this.Validate()

        });

         // works here inside constructor
        this.Validate()
    }
```

The second is to handle it yourself, although this is manually doing what TypeScript would do for you - it is worth knowing that it isn't magic. This can be useful if you don't want to overwrite the meaning of `this` in the event, but want access to the "outer" this too.

```
    constructor() {
        var self = this;

        $("#FormBrokerReferenceID").change(function () {
             = $("#FormBrokerReferenceID").val();

            // Should now work...         
            self.Validate()

        });

         // works here inside constructor
        this.Validate()
    }
```